# How to filter out numbers from a dataframe column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a Pandas dataframe that I've almost cleaned with its various functions.

The bit I can't work out is what is the apply function to remove numbers from the 'region' column.

England6 should be England.

```
    region  admissions_total    admissions_count_men    admissions_count_women  adm_per_100_000_all adm_per_male    adm_per_female  year
11  England6    710562  243565  466978  1322.8  963.1   1685.2  2019
13  North East  24410   8645    15765   932 684 1177    2019
14  Darlington  645 295 355
```

What can I do next?

Comment: `df['region'] = df['region'].str.replace(r'\d+', '', regex=True)`?

Comment: I knew i it was simple but I'm unnerved with regex.

Comment: If you prefer: `df['region'] = df['region'].str.replace(r'[0-9]+', '', regex=True)` ;)